# Dice probability when a number is disallowed in the first round

Tags: probability, dice

In the game Settlers of Catan a player starts each turn rolling 2 six sided dice. There's a variation of the game where if a 7 is rolled in the first round of a game (a 'round' is when each player has taken a turn) it doesn't count an needs to be re-rolled. This must lower the overall probability of a 7 being rolled for the rest of the game (and I'd imagine increase the odds for all the other numbers). How would this probability be calculated?

Comment: "This must lower the overall probability of a 7 being rolled for the rest of the game..." Do you mean you want to compute the probability of rolling a 7 for *subsequent* rolls? This probability is unaltered. How could the dice remember that a 7 was not allowed in the first round? Perhaps instead you mean "What is the probability of rolling a 7 during the *entire* game (including the first round)?". This will indeed be a little lower, but one would need to know the number of rolls in a game to compute it.

Comment: your correct, I was wondering the probability of rolling a 7 for the entire game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are exactly 6 ways to roll a seven with two dice:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{First die} & \text{Second die} \\
\hline
1 & 6 \\ \hline
2 & 5 \\ \hline
3 & 4 \\ \hline
4 & 3 \\ \hline
5 & 2 \\ \hline
6 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}

The total number of ways of rolling two dice is $6 \times 6 = 36$, since there are $6$ ways of rolling each die individually.  Therefore, if you *don't* reroll sevens, you will get a seven with probability $\frac{6}{36} = \frac16$.

If you *do* reroll sevens, during the time you reroll them
you will have $0$ probability of getting a seven.  You will keep rerolling until you get some other case, and each other case is still equally likely, so now there are only $36 - 7 = 29$ cases left, instead of the usual $36$.

The effect of the first round of the game has *no bearing* on the probability of a seven being rolled for the rest of the game.  This is the nature of probability; the two parts of the game are entirely independent.  However, one other thing we can compute that maybe you wanted to know is how much rerolling sevens increases the probability of rolling other things.  Well, each individual case (such as 1, 1 or 3, 1) now has probability $\frac1{29}$ of being rolled instead of the original $\frac{1}{36}$, so the probability has increased by
$$
\frac{1/29}{1/36} = \frac{39}{29} \approx 1.24137
$$
when sevens are rerolled.
So each number (2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12) appears about $24$ percent more often than normal during the first round.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Comment: how would I go about calculating the probability for the entire game and not just the first round?

Comment: @greatwitenorth I assume you mean the average probability of a seven for the whole game.  On average, if there are $N$ rounds, the first will have a $0$ percent chance and the other $(N - 1)$ will have a $\frac16$ chance, so the average probability will be $\frac{1 \cdot 0 + (N-1)\frac16}{N} = \frac{N-1}{6N}$.  As a mildly educated guess, let's say since you have to get 10 victory points to win, and you already have 2, the game will take 2 rounds for each additional victory point, in total 16 rounds.  Then we have that the average probability is about $\frac{15}{6 \cdot 16} = \frac{5}{32}$.

Comment: This is approximately $.156$.  So about 15.6 percent of all dice rolls in the game are sevens.  If there were no special rules for the first round, about 16.7 percent (1/6) of all rolls would be sevens.

Comment: Let me know if this is what you wanted or if there is anything else you wanted to ask for.

Comment: Yes that clears things up. I'm making a program that will continually calculate the entire avg up until that point in the game. So instead of calculating on the per round basis, could I just treat N as each turn and minus by 6 (or however many players are in the game)? ie. on turn number 9 there would be a (9-6)/(6*9) = 1/18 avg probability of 7 showing up until that point in the game then on turn 10 there would be a (10-6)/(6*10) = 1/15 avg probability. Would this be correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8823/discussion-between-greatwitenorth-and-goos)